# Can someone explain the Angular subscribe method

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am just learning Angular by reading tutorial for for v.4.0. I just got to the [Section 6](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) (Routing) of that tutorial and I got stuck on understanding the `subscribe` method. I would be gratefull for some more explanation on it.

I understand that `ngOnInit()` is called just once so thats why we use `subscribe()` here. But what event makes `subscribe()` to get triggered? Is it triggered only when the page containing that particular `HeroDetailComponent` is requested again. For my understanding it must be attached to some kind of 'onChange' event on ActivatedRoute.params, and is triggered while the user requests the same page(containing `HeroDetailComponent`).

Once `ActivatedRoute.params` change what happens then? I mean - How does it happen that `this.hero` is assigned a new value, if the `ngOnInit()` is executed only once. I'm curious how does it know to execute `this.heroService.getHero(+params['id'])`  and assign returned value to `this.hero`?

Complete source code from the tutorial [here](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-6/ts/eplnkr.html)

```
// mock-heroes.ts
export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];

// hero.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
    }
    getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
      return this.getHeroes()
         .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
    }

// hero-detail.component.ts
@Component({...})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(
        private heroService: HeroService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private location: Location
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
        .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
    }
```

***EDIT***:
I've just found a [great article](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-rxjs-common-pitfalls/) which might be usefull if someone have problem understanding these concepts.

Comment: See here: http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/subscribe.html and https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `subscribe()` is part of rxjs, not angular. For full understanding how it works - go to rxjs documentation :)

2) For basic understanding, imagine that you have class/object something like (real `Observable` is much more complicate, that is just pseudo code):

```
type CallbackFunction = () => void;

class ObservableImitation{

    private subscribers: CallbackFunction[] = [];

    constructor(){};

    public subscribe(callback: CallbackFunction){
        this.subscribers.push(callback);
    }

    public next(value?: any){
        this.subscribers.forEach((callback: CallbackFunction) => callback(value));
    }

}
```

Basically, when you `.subscribe()`, your callback is added to array. When something else calls `.next()` (in case of `Router` it is called inside of its code) on `Observable` it starts looping on all `subscribers`.

To prevent unexpected memory leaks and errors, you better should `unsubscribe()`, when your Component is destroyed (if it is destroyed at all, for example, some abstract `NavBarComponent` always stays on screen).

More important is how typescript/js/es resolves `this` for callback. But that is question for another topic. All you have to consider at this point, as soon as you do

```
.subscribe(() => {
    this.doSomething();
    this.doSomethingElse();
});
```

or

```
.subscribe(() => this.doSomething());
```

or

```
.subscribe(this.doSomething.bind(this));
```

everything works fine.